# how to set the color of all points in a line graph to the same in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The pointBackgroundColor only changes the color of the first point of the data,i want to set all the points to the same color,how to do it?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('itemschart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: itemnames,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Revenue by individual items',
                data: itemprice,
                fill:false,

                borderColor: [
                'rgb(51, 153, 255)',
                ],
                pointBackgroundColor:[
                'rgb(51, 153, 255)',

                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use an array. In an array you define each color of the chart. First array element is first chart point, second array element is second chart point... You just define the color of the first element.

If you write `borderColor: 'rgb(51, 153, 255)'` the color is applied to every point.